# Problems building cca android app on mac

Tags: android, macos, cordova, google-chrome-app, cordova-chrome-app

I've recently updated a few dependencies on my mac after a while not doing much cca development and now the "cca run android" command is no longer working on my machine.

I get the following strange error:

```
BUILD FAILED
<my project path>/platforms/android/build.xml:90: Cannot find  /usr/local/tools/ant/build.xml imported from <my project path>/platforms/android/build.xml

Total time: 0 seconds

<my project directory>/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                throw e;
                 ^
Error code 1 for command: ant with args: debug,-f,<my project directory>/platforms/android/build.xml,-Dsdk.dir=/usr/local
```

It's looking for a build file that doesn't exist.  I'm concerned about the section that says **-Dsdk.dir=/usr/local**.  Clearly it should be looking at my android home directory, which seems to be set properly:

```
$ echo $ANDROID_HOME
/usr/local/opt/android-sdk
```

And if that variable was being set properly, it would find one:

ls $ANDROID_HOME/tools/ant/build.xml
   /usr/local/opt/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml

Has anyone run into this recently using recent versions of cca with android?  Hoping there's some obvious mistake I'm making that can be easily remedied.

Comment: Quick test: is your ANDROID_HOME exported so that other processes can see it?  To do a quick test, type "bash" (or whatever shell you want) and then echo the variable there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a response from the MobileChromeApps developers on their [github issue tracker](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/issues/190). It turns out that the sdk.dir was not being set by the $ANDROID_HOME variable, but instead by the $PATH variable that matches the first android executable.  By fixing my path to move $ANDROID_HOME before anything else in the path it fixed the issue, and they filed [a bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7044) to prioritize $ANDROID_HOME in a future build.